# Laravel 8 jetstream: Login.blade.php and Register.blade.php pages display issue

Tags: laravel

After installed jetstream ...I got the login and Register button on top right corner. when I click on login or Register the Logo display in large logo and the form display left bottom corner with : email: input box, password..(login page and register same issues).
Not sure how to fix it. Other previous I can catch up ok.
Any one can assist me or email a hint to fix the logo in center and small and form login and register should be in middle of page?
Thanks and regards
thdinh201197@yahoo.com
TD

Comment: it seems issue with css .. did you run `npm install && npm run dev`?

Comment: On stack overflow we answer code based questions on SO so it helps other people with the same problem, please don't ask for answers on email.